# pandas operations inside a for-loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Here is a sample of my data

```
threats =
                                  binomial_name
    continent        threat_type    
    Africa  Agriculture & Aquaculture   143
              Biological Resource Use   102
                    Climate Change       3
               Commercial Development   36
           Energy Production & Mining   30
    ... ... ...
    South America   Human Intrusions    1
                     Invasive Species   3
        Natural System Modifications    1
              Transportation Corridor   2
                             Unknown    38
```

I want to use a for loop and obtain and append together the top 5 values of each continent into a data frame.
Here is my code -

```
continents = threats.continent.unique()

for i in continents:
    continen = (threats
           .query('continent == i')
           .groupby(['continent','threat_type'])
           .sort_values(by=('binomial_name'), ascending=False).
           .head())

    top5 = appended_data.append(continen)
```

I am however getting the error - `KeyError: 'i'`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.query(f'continent == {i}')` ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not just `df.sort_values('binomial_name').groupby('continent').nlargest(5)`?

Comment: @Marat this is the error - AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'nlargest' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @jakub - nope, still getting an error

Comment: this is not an exact code (should filter by a particular column), but the question still holds - is there something preventing from using standard pandas functions? It could be done as a one-liner

Comment: No, nothing is preventing from using standard pandas functions.  But I'm still not sure on how we could filter for each value in continents without a loop :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the canonical way to do this:

```
df.groupby('continent', as_index=False).apply(
    lambda grp: grp.nlargest(5, 'binomial_value'))
```

If you want to do this in a loop, replace this part:

```
for i in continents: 
    continen = threats[threats['continent'] == i].nlargest(2, 'binomial_name') 
    appended_data.append(continen)
```

Comment: I still am getting an error via the loop approach. Here is my code                                   
     `continents = threats.continent.unique()                                                               
     for i in continents:
     continents = threats[threats['continent'] == i].nlargest(5, 'binomial_value')

            top5 = appended_data.append(continen)`

Comment: what error do you get? Can you post a sample of the data?

Comment: Sure, I've posted a sample of my data in the question